# How to find unique values in a field of a nested struct

Tags: matlab, struct, nested, unique

I have a nested struct user.data and I want to find the unique values of the field touristicRoute (user.data.touristicRoute)

I have tried this code:

```
for m=1:size(Cluster_USERS,1)
    for i=1:size(userTouristicTraj(m).touristicData,2)
        if (user(m).data(i).touristicRoute~=0)
            uniqueValues=unique(user(m).data(i).touristicRoute)
        end
    end
end
```

but it doesn't give me the right value, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unique value of a single struct is that value itself. If you want to see the unique values of all structs, then you need to extract them first.

```
for m=1:size(Cluster_USERS,1)
    for i=1:size(userTouristicTraj(m).touristicData,2)
        if (user(m).data(i).touristicRoute~=0)
            for jj=size(user(m).data(i).touristicRoute,1)
            values=unique([(user(m).data(i).touristicRoute{jj}).' values]);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: the code gives an error: 'Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.'

Comment: @elis56 try now

Comment: @elis56 What does `user.data.touristicRoute` contain?

Comment: user.data.touristicRoute contain data of this type 'user(1).data(1).touristicRoute={[1;0];[1;1;1];[1;1;1;1;1];[1;1;1;1;1;1;1];[2;2];[0;0;0];[2;2];[0;0];[0;0];[0;0];[1;1];[0;0];[1;1];[0;0];[0;0];[0;0];[0;0];[2;2;2];[0;0]}'

Comment: And you want `unique` of that? `unique` what? Integers? combinations?

Comment: @elis56 if the latest edit does not work, please add a couple of examples in the question